# How to make LED flashlight to blink on call receive?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make the LED flash light to blink when the device receive an incoming call. This is how am doing it in a Service Class.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
Camera cam = null;
boolean offhook = false;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra("state");

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
        if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH) && !offhook) {


                String myString = "01010101010101010101";
                long blinkDelay = 50;



                for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
                    if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                        // params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                        cam = Camera.open();
                        Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        cam.setParameters(p);
                    } else {
                        // params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        offhook = true;
                        if (cam != null) {
                            cam.stopPreview();
                            cam.release();
                            cam = null;
                        }
                        this.stopSelf();
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }



        }
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
        if (!offhook) {
            if (cam != null) {
                cam.release();
                cam = null;
            }
            this.stopSelf();
        } else {
            offhook = false;
        }
    }

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
        offhook = true;
        if (cam != null) {
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.release();
            cam = null;
        }
        this.stopSelf();
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (cam != null) {
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

But the blink not getting stopped even after i attend or reject the call since its in a for loop. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your code in onStartCommand as this method will be executed on main thread, so it's likely that you may get ANR.
To stop your LED blink, interrupt the thread when you answer or reject the call and place a for loop break to come out of the loop.

Comment: @carl Manaster : How to break the for loop?

Comment: Sorry - this is @Ayaanp's answer; I just edited it to clean up the grammar.  I don't know.

Comment: inside catch block of InterruptedException you can place break statement.

Comment: you need to interrupt the thread... from EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK
give a name to your thread as i said before and call threadname.interrupt